# Найти длину самой длинной последовательности, состоящей из символов R

Tags: python, информатика

Текстовый файл состоит не более чем из 10^6 символов L, D и R. Определите длину самой длинной последовательности, состоящей из символов R.

Сразу скажу, я в пайтоне новичок, поэтому всё, что смог написать так это:

```python
f = open("zadanie24_2.txt")
s = f.readlines()
m = 0
for i in s:
    if s(i) == "R" and s(i + 1) == "RR":
        m+=1
print(m)
```

Прилетела вот такая ошибка

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\staso\OneDrive\Рабочий Стол\Py\Exam\Option 1\24.py", line 5, in <module>
    if s(i) == "R" and s(i + 1) == "RR":
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

Где-то в инете нашёл этот код, в него подставлял свои значения, но опять же ничего не вышло

```python
# откроем файл на чтение
F = open ('zadanie24_2.txt', 'rt')

# T - список файла F
T = F.read ().split ()

K = 1 # K - число одинаковых чисел
A = [] # список длин цепочек одинаковых чисел
for i in range (0, len (T) - 1) :
  #print (T [i], end = '')
  if T [i] == T [i + 1] :
    K += 1
  else :
    A += [K]
    K = 1

A += [K]

F.close ()

R = open ('result.txt', 'wt')
R.write (str (max (A)))

R.close ()
print ('Файл result.txt записан')
```

Помогите, кто может

Comment: Для начала скажу причину ошибки в первом коде. В python индексы указываются в квадратных скобках, а не в круглых

Comment: Также вы не понимаете смысла строки for i in s. Циклы подобной формы в качестве переменной i принимают не число, а объект, входящий в список. Если вам нужен перебор индексов в цикле, попробуйте что-то вроде for i in range(0, len(s))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. индексы надо писать в квадратные скобки, а не в круглые
2. `for i in s` так вы проходитесь по всем элементам, а вам надо все индексы. надо так `for i in range(len(s) - 1)`
3. `s[i + 1] == "RR"` вы берете один элемент а сравнивает с двумя. надо так `s[i + 1] == "R"`
4. вы не где не сохраняете и не обнуляите значение `m`

```
f = open("zadanie24_2.txt")
s = f.read()
m = 1
maxlen = 0
for i in range(len(s) - 1):
    if s[i] == "R" and s[i + 1] == "R":
        m += 1
        if mexlen < m:
            maxlen = m 
    else:
        m = 1
if maxlen == 0 and "R" in s:
    maxlen = 1
print(maxlen)
```

Comment: Большое спасибо! Заработало)

Comment: Ответ же не рабочий ;) Фейл будет на "AAA" и на "ARARR"

Comment: @MBo а теперь?.

Comment: А теперь на `ARA`.

Comment: @MBo а теперь?.

Comment: Да работает всё. Я в файле последовательность символов менял, ответ верный выдавало

Comment: @g1shy Я привёл примеры, на который первоначальный код ошибался.

Answer (score 2):

Пройдём по индексам строки. Встретили R - запомнили индекс начала. Встретили не R - вычислили длину серии.

```
r = False
maxlen = 0
for i in range(len(s)+1):
    if i<len(s) and s[i] == "R":
        if not r:
            start = i
            r = True
    else:
        if r:
            maxlen = max(maxlen, i - start)
            r = False
print(maxlen)
```

Answer (score 0):

вот мой вариант решения:
где curLen - временное хранение длины последовательности,
maxLen - максимальная длина последовательности,
s - строка для работы с символами из файла,
i - переменная для перебора всех символов.

```
f = open("zadanie24.txt")
maxLen = 1
curLen = 1
s = f.readline()
for i in range(2, len(s)):
        if s[i] == s[i-1] and s[i]== 'R':
            curLen = curLen+1
            if curLen > maxLen:
                maxLen = curLen
        else:
            curLen=1
print(maxLen)
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот вариант в одну строку - на основании строки s создаем список с счетчиками искомого символа, далее берем максимальное значение счетчика (нулевой символ добавляем к строке, чтобы избежать ошибок с пустой строкой):

```
i = 0
maxLen = max((i := i + 1) if ch == 'R' else (i := 0) for ch in st + [0])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
f = open("zadanie24_2.txt").read()
f = f.replace("L", " ").replace("D", " ").split()
f.sort()
print(len(max(f)))
```

Comment: Сортировка не нужна, достаточно просто максимум брать.